# Mock Child Actors Akka Java with Specific Ids

Tags: java, akka

I am working with `Akka 2.5.23`. I have a parent actor that `forwards` a `Register Message` to a child and the child replies to the `original sender` with an `Initialized message`.

I am facing some tough time unit testing this code flow. I am trying to [externalize child creation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html#externalize-child-making-from-the-parent) for the parent but cannot seem to figure out how to pass define the name of the `child actor` while creating the child actor

Below is my `ParentActor`

```
public class ParentActor extends AbstractLoggingActor {

    private final Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childMaker;

    public ParentActor() {
        this.childMaker = arg -> {
            return context().actorOf(ChildActor.props("ID", appContext), "ACTOR_NAME");
        };
    }

    private void handleRegisterMessage(RegisterMessage message){

        childMaker.apply(context());

        // what I generally do:
        // context().actorOf(ChildActor.props(message.getUniqueId(), "TransChild-" + message.getUniqueId());

    }
}
```

Below is my `ChildActor`:

```
public class ChildActor extends AbstractLoggingActor {

    private final String uniqueId;

    public ChildActor(String uniqueId){
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public static Props props(String uniqueId) {
        return Props.create(ChildActor.class, uniqueId);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

> he Ids are generated based on input message. The parent creates a child actor with a specific id (derived from message). That unique ID is passed to the child via `Props` and the child on `PreStart()` performs operations based on the passed uniqueId via Props

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand which part is the problem, but, you could:

Make the "childMaker" a `BiFunction<String, ActorRefFactory, ActorRef>` instead and create named children in the main one using `but return a probe or spawned test specific actor in the test.

So instead of `f -> f.actorOf(Props.create(Child.class))` you'd do `(name, f) -> f.actorOf(props, name)`

To be honest I'd probably not use a lambda but define a `protected ActorRef spawnChild(RegisterMessage message)` method in the Actor class in Java instead and override that in the test. Will probably be more clear, not sure why we have such an example in the docs.

Comment: interesting approach, I do agree with you on the externalizing approach being not clear. Would be able to share some sample working code that I can try especially with the overriding I am not sure I completely understand it?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in our samples, but here's a short one I threw together, I hope it helps: https://gist.github.com/johanandren/6f7891ad455f923f3fcae44fd94609a2 (ups github broke the formatting but perhaps copy paste it into some IDE will fix that)

Answer (score -1):

You can either use a counter and append at the end of the actor name you want to give to that actor. Like,

```
public ParentActor() {
        int counter = 0;
        this.childMaker = arg -> {
            return context().actorOf(ChildActor.props("ID", appContext), "ACTOR_NAME" + counter++);
        };
    }
```

You cannot create multiple actors of the same name.  For more information about actor creation, you can read [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#creating-actors-with-props).

Comment: please have a look at the question, the Ids are dynamic and not really incremental. In the code I've shared `message.getUniqueId()`

Comment: Okay. Can you explain a bit more on your requirement?

Comment: Sure, the Ids are generated based on input message. The parent creates a child actor with a specific id (derived from message). That unique ID is passed to the child via `Props` and the child on `PreStart()` performs operations based on the passed uniqueId via Props

Comment: Okay, now I got your use case. Can you explain what problem you are facing in doing so?

Comment: `childMaker.apply()`  doesn't have a flexibility to set the name of the actor dynamically and not pass dynamic arguments to the child actor. Please read about externalizing child actor from the link in the question

Comment: Did you try taking the generated `Id` in child class Constructor and use that as the child actor name?

Comment: Yes we can but then how do you pass that as props while actor creation using a child maker? which exactly is the question.